# Issue with Varnish

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

We are developing a website with React and Redux. We have just added a Varnish cache on our API and, although everything seems to work well when testing the API on Postman, this is not working fine on our website.

For some reason, all API queries are failing with an 401 status code the first time that they are done, however, they works fine after having failed the first time.

This behaviour has just started happening once we have added Varnish cache, but, we are unable to found the error.

The Varnish configuration file is as follows:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = ...;
    .port = ...;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 5m;

    # Don't cache non-200 responses
    if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }
    # Don't cache if "no-cache" or "private" on cache control
    if (beresp.http.cache-control ~ "(no-cache|private)" ||
        beresp.http.pragma ~ "no-cache") {
            set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }

}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Do not cache Healthcheck call
    if (req.url == "/api/healthcheck") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Do not cache POST methods
    if (req.method == "POST") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Do not cache users' calls as each user will be different
    if (req.url ~ "\/api\/v[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/users\/.*") {
        return (pass);
    } 

    # Ensure that cache is enabled to any call to the API
    if (req.url ~ "/api/*") {
        return (hash);
    }   
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  if (req.url ~ "/api/*") {
    set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Type, Dnt, Origin, User-Agent, X-CSRFToken, X-Requested-With";
    return (deliver);
  } 
}
```

What may be going on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Based on getting ```401``` which is unauthorised - how do you authenticate API requests? Some header's value / query param / POST data? More details please :)

Comment: The authorization is done through a token send on the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found my issue, there was an return(hash) missing on my configuration file.

The right configuration file is as follows:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = ...;
    .port = ...;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.ttl = 5m;

    # Don't cache non-200 responses
    if ( beresp.status != 200 ) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }
    # Don't cache if "no-cache" or "private" on cache control
    if (beresp.http.cache-control ~ "(no-cache|private)" ||
        beresp.http.pragma ~ "no-cache") {
            set beresp.ttl = 0s;
    }

}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Do not cache Healthcheck call
    if (req.url == "/api/healthcheck") {
        return (pass);
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
        return (pass);
    }

    # Do not cache users' calls as each user will be different
    if (req.url ~ "\/api\/v[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/users\/.*") {
        return (pass);
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  if (req.url ~ "/api/*") {
    set resp.http.Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Authorization, Content-Type, Dnt, Origin, User-Agent, X-CSRFToken, X-Requested-With";
    return (deliver);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure I'd still post for people who apply Varnish to API requests that require authorization of some kind (even you say you solved your problem).

If you happen to require authorization for paths *outside* `\/api\/v[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+\/users\/.*` scope, then 401s might still happen because those requests might still be cached.

Furthermore, you can (and should, for performance reasons) cache authenticated requests as well. Simple solution to that and 401 error would be to vary your cache by the token header's value.

### Solution 1.

You can change your application code to simply send the extra HTTP header: `Vary: X-Token`. This is enough to instruct Varnish that cache should be different between different users of your API.

### Solution 2.

If you have no way to adjust your app, then some VCL can come to help:

```cpp
sub vcl_backend_response {
     if (!beresp.http.Vary) { # no Vary at all
        set beresp.http.Vary = "X-Token";
    } elsif (beresp.http.Vary !~ "X-Token") { # add to existing Vary
        set beresp.http.Vary = beresp.http.Vary + ", X-Token";
    }
    ...
}
```

P.S. it is generally not recommended to put "trailing" `return` in `vcl_recv` to ensure that the [builtin vcl_recv](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/4.0/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L47) routines would still run.